# Android: how to set set background color to button using selector with stroke?

Tags: android, android-layout, selector

I have the following selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/divider"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Which is used as background for the button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/delete"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/delete_button_stroke"
    android:text="@string/minus"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

I makes a border around the button, but background color of the button is transparent.

How can i set background color and background color for pressed button using the selector please?

Many thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create two ShapeDrawable xml files in your *res/drawable* folder like this:

**btn_state_normal.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid
        android:color="#ffff00"
    />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#0000ff"
    />
    <padding
        android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
    />
    <size
        android:height="10dp"
        android:width="10dp"
    />
</shape>
```

**btn_state_pressed.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid
        android:color="#ff0000"
    />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#00ff00"
        android:dashWidth="4dp"
        android:dashGap="2dp"
    />
    <padding
        android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
    />
    <size
        android:height="10dp"
        android:width="10dp"
    />
</shape>
```

Note that the size values don't matter with `(Image)Button`s, the drawables are stretched to fit.

Then your selector should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_state_normal"
        android:state_pressed="false"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_state_pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
</selector>
```

Because `android:state_pressed="false"` is set in the first item, the next one will be used for the pressed state.

See also the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) for `StateListDrawable`

Answer (score 0):

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/divider"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
 <color android:color="@color/abc_search_url_text_normal"/>// add this line it should work.
    </selector>
```

Comment: Cannot set @color/my_color  

from colors.xml